# Check if a string pattern matches a list of blobs and write as output (Powershell)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I'm retrieving a list of blobs from an Azure Storage Account. I have a folder structure with dozens of folder-names and multiple blobs in it.
I was successful to list the blobs, count them per folder and check if a certain string-pattern matches to one of the blobs. If it matches, it gives the matching status for each string as yes or no.
But I was not able to modify it so I have the matched search string as column name.

Currently the script produces this as output:

```
foldername, blobcount, matchstatus
4010009104797,"366","False, True, True, True, True, True"
4010009106951,"366","False, True, True, True, True, True"
4010009107064,"366","False, True, True, True, True, True"
```

I have dynamically changing string patterns (variable in name and amount). I want to have it like this:

```
foldername, blobcount, stringA, stringB, stringC, stringd, stringe, stringf
4010009104797,"366","True, True, True, True, True, True"
4010009106951,"366","True, True, True, True, True, True"
4010009107064,"366","True, True, True, True, True, True"
```

The strings as column names shall be exact the same as the defined search pattern strings.

My code so far:

```html
function Get-FolderBlobCount {
    param (
        [string]$StorageAccountName,
        [string]$StorageAccountKey,
        [string]$ContainerName,
        [string]$SubPath = "",
        [string[]]$SearchStrings,
        [string]$OutputFilePath
    )

    # Authenticate to Azure Storage
    $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

    # Get the list of blobs in the specified container and folder
    $blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $ContainerName -Prefix $SubPath

    # Group blobs by folder
    $blobsByFolder = $blobs | Group-Object { $_.Name -replace "/[^/]+$" }

    # Initialize a result array to store folder information
    $result = @()

    # Iterate through each folder
    foreach ($folder in $blobsByFolder) {
        # Initialize variables for blob count and match status
        $blobCount = 0
        $searchStringsMatched = @($false) * $SearchStrings.Count

        # Iterate through blobs in the folder
        foreach ($blob in $folder.Group) {
            # Check if each search string has at least one match in the blob name
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $SearchStrings.Count; $i++) {
                if ($blob.Name -like $SearchStrings[$i]) {
                    $searchStringsMatched[$i] = $true
                }
            }

            # Increment blob count
            $blobCount++
        }

        # Add the folder information to the result array
        $result += [PSCustomObject]@{
            FolderName = $folder.Name
            BlobCount = $blobCount
            MatchStatus = $searchStringsMatched -join ', '
        }

        # Output search string matching status for debugging
        Write-Host "Folder: $($folder.Name), Blob Count: $blobCount, Match Status: $($searchStringsMatched -join ', ')"
    }

    # Export the result array to a CSV file
    $result | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFilePath -NoTypeInformation

    Write-Host "Results written to $OutputFilePath"
}

# Provide your Azure Storage account details
$storageAccountName = "X"
$storageAccountKey = "Y"
$containerName = "Z"
$subPath = "A"  # Replace with the desired sub-path, leave empty for root

$searchStrings = @(
    "*X_*Y_*Z001*.jpg",
    "*X_*Y_*Z002*.jpg",
    "*X_*Y_*Z003*.jpg",
    "*X_*Y_*Z004*.jpg",
    "*X_*Y_*Z005*.jpg",
    "*X_*Y_*Z006*.jpg",
)  # Replace with your actual search strings
$outputFilePath = "C:\OutputFileTT.csv"  # Replace with your desired output file path

# Call the function with the specified parameters
Get-FolderBlobCount -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey -ContainerName $containerName -SubPath $subPath -SearchStrings $searchStrings -OutputFilePath $outputFilePath
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more practical to have a fixed number of columns and then store the matched strings instead of True/False? So a row would look something like `4010009104797,"366","stringB, stringC, stringd, stringe, stringf"`?

Comment: Yes, thats also fine. How do I do that? :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, it might be more practical to keep your variable-length results in a single column, but instead of storing the boolean results of the individual comparisons, store the search term that was matched instead.

Change this section:

```
        # Initialize variables for blob count and match status
        $blobCount = 0
        $searchStringsMatched = @($false) * $SearchStrings.Count

        # Iterate through blobs in the folder
        foreach ($blob in $folder.Group) {
            # Check if each search string has at least one match in the blob name
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $SearchStrings.Count; $i++) {
                if ($blob.Name -like $SearchStrings[$i]) {
                    $searchStringsMatched[$i] = $true
                }
            }

            # Increment blob count
            $blobCount++
        }
```

to

```
        # Initialize variable for blob count
        $blobCount = 0

        # Iterate through blobs in the folder
        foreach ($blob in $folder.Group) {
            # Check if each search string has at least one match in the blob name, filter the rest out
            $searchStringsMatched = @(
                $SearchStrings |Where-Object { $blob.Name -like $_ }
            )

            # Increment blob count
            $blobCount++
        }
```